# Function for retrieving html data through database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Can anyone help me for the function for retrieving html data using webview through database

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

As you haven't mention which DB you are using, that is why i am not able to add code for that. Once you fetch data from DB you can pass string to loadHTMLString.

[UIWebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)